# Server Timeout Error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, timeoutexception

**I'm having problems executing a calculation procedure through an ASP.NET site to SQL Server.  Not much detail, I know, but hoping someone on here can help.  The procedure works in some instances and in some it does not.  Here is the error message when the calculation bombs....**

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1948826
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4844747
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +204
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   Database.ExportFas143CostData(Int32 PermitNameID, Int32 FiscalYear, Int32 FiscalMonth, Int32 CashFlowYear, Decimal WeightedCost) in d:\CC.NET\AROTest_web\ARO_Web\App_Code\Database.cs:1777
   AroCalculations.CalculateReclamation(String ReclamationDataID, String PermitNameID) in d:\CC.NET\AROTest_web\ARO_Web\AroCalculations.aspx.cs:390
   AroCalculations.CalculateSelected_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\CC.NET\AROTest_web\ARO_Web\AroCalculations.aspx.cs:359
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +79
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

Comment: The error pretty plainly tells you what the problem is. SQL is timing out. How long does the query or proc take to run if you do it in SSMS?

Comment: Run SQL Profiler to see what SQL is running at the time. You either need to increase the timeout, or do some performance tuning on the query. Also this is ASP.Net, not ASP Classic.

Answer (score 3):

There are few things you can try

1. Increase **[SQLCommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)**
2. Increase **[HttpRuntime's Execution Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout.aspx)** out property in web.config file, if your query takes more than request default time
3. Increase **[ScriptTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524831%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** property
4. Run SQL Proffiler and optimize the SQL procedure, if it takes more time(with the help of Query Analyser and Database Tuning Adviser (DTA))